# Keycloak custom Authentication

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper, louketo-proxy

I am new to Keycloak, now i trying to add a custom authenticator, i just get source from [link](https://github.com/UKGovernmentBEIS/keycloak-sms-authenticator-sns) this url and build the jar and deployed in keyclaok jboss deployment folder add tried to added under provider folder also.

But keycloak server not showing my custom autheticator in authentication flows in keycloak.

[Screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIl2L.png)

[Screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnNRq.png)

anyone please help me on this